# Compound nouns versus Modified nouns

Tags: compound-words

1/ Can all noun modifier + head-noun constructions be regarded as compounds ?
2/ How can we test or identify that a two-noun word is a compound or just an
   attributive noun + noun construction ? Please give examples.

Thank you.

Comment: No: compounds are single words -- morphological compounds consisting of two smaller bases, e.g. "cotton-plant", "matchbox". By contrast, head+modifier is a syntactic construction, two separate words, e.g. "cotton shirt", " cutlery box". There are several tests for distinguishing compounds and syntactic constructions, e.g. in a syntactic construction the component parts can enter separately into a coordination. Take "cutlery box" vs "matchbox: "I collect antique cutlery and wine-glass boxes" is fine, but not *"I collect antique match and dinky toy boxes". "Matchbox" is thus a compound.

Comment: Consider also "blackcurrant" vs "television screen". The former cannot enter into a coordination -- we wouldn't normally say "I like black and red currants", so it must be a compound.  But we can say "Television and computer screens have different resolutions", so "television screen" is a syntactic construction consisting of head + modifier. There can in some cases be some blurring of the distinction, but you won't go far wrong if you take all single words as compounds and all separate words as syntactic constructions.